# Returning child properties in JSON from Django Models

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a database model setup in Django to track portfolios and am trying to develop a API to return a portfolio along with each coin in it, and each transaction associated with the coin. However using the api i only see the name field of my model being returned. Some code for clarification:

model.py:

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    @property
    def coins(self):
        return Coin.objects.filter(portfolio=self)

    def transactions(self):
        return Transaction.objects.filter(portfolio=self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Coin(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=9)
    info = models.TextField()
    website = models.TextField()
    rank = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " - " + self.symbol


class Transaction(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coin = models.ForeignKey(Coin, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    purchaseDate = models.DateTimeField()
    soldDate = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=9)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.coin.name + " - " + str(self.amount) + " At $" + str(self.price)
```

My json serializer:

```
class PortfolioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
        fields = '__all__'
```

How data comes back:

```
 HTTP 200 OK
    Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
    Content-Type: application/json
    Vary: Accept

    [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Binance"
        }
    ]
```

What I want is in the data set, under binance it should show a list of coin objects, which contained a list of transactions for each coin.

Comment: Can't you remove the property coins and just call `portfolio.coins` because of the foreign key relation you made in `Coin`? This isn't part of the solution to your question but you are creating a property while Django has already made this one for u. Also why is transaction suddenly not a property? You should check that. Besides by doing it this way, you are creating two extra queries that aren't necessary at all!

Answer (score 1):

You really should read the [Django-Rest-Framework docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships):

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    @property
    def coins(self):
        return Coin.objects.filter(portfolio=self)

    def transactions(self):
        return Transaction.objects.filter(portfolio=self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Coin(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, relared_name="coins" ,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=9)
    info = models.TextField()
    website = models.TextField()
    rank = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " - " + self.symbol
```

In your PortfolioSerializer:

```
class PortfolioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coins = CoinSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
        fields = '__all__'
```

There you should write a `CoinSerializer` in the above of `PortfolioSerializer`, such as:

```
class CoinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Coin
            fields = '__all__'
```